# Geocoding IOException trying to run a search for nearest hospitals

Tags: android, geocoding

I am trying to incorporate and hospital search in my app. It is supposed to give the closest 5 hospitals based upon your location.

I am getting an IOException with List geocodeResults= coder.getFromLocationName(strLocation, 5); in Eclipse with coder.getFromLocationName(strLocation, 5); underlined being the issue.

I have also set the permissions for location coarse and fine as well as internet and still I am getting this error.

I would also like to take these 5 results and list them with the hospital name, address and miles away.

I am still new at coding for the android. I have come across a lot of great and useful help by searching this site, so here is where I am asking.

Either this or I want my app to send the string "hospital" to google maps and let google maps app display the results. I don't care which.

Thanx in advance for all the help

To be honest I do not completely understand the code I listed above, I understand some but not all. I do know it is a necessity to help me accomplish my goal.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. With most Android issues that cause an error or crash, the community will be able to help you better if you post the exception traceback from the app and any other relevant information from the Android logs using the `logcat` tool that comes with the Android SDK. To run logcat, execute `adb logcat` from your Android SDK `tools/` directory or, from DDMS, select Device > Run logcat. When using the ADT plugin for Eclipse, you can also view logcat messages by opening the Logcat view, available from Window > Show View > Other > Android > Logcat.

Comment: this isn't even crash...well not yet yet. In Eclipse, as I am writing the code this popped up. As long as this error exists, I will never be able to run it.

Comment: ctr+shift+o ?
anyways you should probably wrap that in a try/catch block.

Comment: The other thing I don't have the slightest idea where to truly begin. I got this code from a book I'm trying to work from.

Comment: You might also read more on Geocoder as well as location services

Answer (score 4):

If your'e using Geocoder in the Emulator you will have some IO Exceptions. Actually Geocoder is not the most reliable service and frequently issues a "Service Unavailable" IO Exception. There have been some of us that have looped at the Geocoder call until it comes back clean and others who have tried other measures.

I think the emulator in 2.3 and above has a bug item on this and in 2.2 below it works rather sporadically.

This bit of code will output the actual exception to a toast message and will logcat the exception as well.

```
        String strAddress = "your address here/or location";

        try{
         List<Address> loc = geocoder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
         Log.e("IOException", e.getMessage());

         //Toaster on high-----------------//
     Context context = getApplicationContext();
     CharSequence text = "IOException:  " + e.getMessage();
     int dur = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            Toast.makeText(context, text, dur).show();
```